# There's a way to make a generic persist? [Java Console]

Tags: java, generics, console

I have this situation:
I have a base class

```
public class Vehicle 
{
    private String atrb1;
    private String atrb2;
}
```

And some classes that inherit from it

```
public class Car extends Vehicle 
{
    private String anotheratrb1;
}

public class Bus extends Vehicle { ... }

public class Truck extends Vehicle { ... }
```

I'm doing a Java  Console Application, and the user can choose the type of vehicle he wants to register, is there any way to get the type of vehicle he typed and through a method decide which class that inherit from vehicle I will persist the bank? Without any switch-cases and ifs, using something like generics, because in the future the user will have the option to add new types, and this can break a switch-case or if-else for example.

I did a lot of research and found reflection. There's another way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need reflection.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for the awnser! Is there any problem to use reflection in a situation like this(using console...)?

Comment: I think you need an enum class X, which has factory method such as `public static X of(String)`. To avoid the use of `if-else`s, I think you should have a static map that associates the string representation to its enum constant. Every enum constant should have the string representation, and a method to create the object of associated class, such as Car, Bus, and Truck.

Comment: @bjlee72 Thanks! Could you show me a little example? It was a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I attach an example. Later I think you can extend this class to have more constants - just don't forget to add corresponding lines in the `static` block. One more thing to comment is, below is for Java 1.7. If you use 1.8, you can use more elegant solution of passing `Car::new` to VehicleType constructor, instead of passing `Car.class`.

```
enum VehicleType {
    CAR("car", Car.class),
    TRUCK("truck", Truck.class);

    private static Map<String, VehicleType> types = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        types.put(CAR.asString(), CAR);
        types.put(TRUCK.asString(), TRUCK);
    }

    private String str;
    private Class<? extends Vehicle> clazz;

    VehicleType(String str, Class<? extends Vehicle> clazz) {
        this.str = str;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    static VehicleType of(String str) {
        return types.get(str);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    <T extends Vehicle> T createInstance() {
        try {
            return (T) this.clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // there's no default constructor.
            return null;
        }
    }

    String asString() {
        return this.str;
    }
}
```